# May one wear all white tzitzit and techeiles at the same time?

Tags: tzitzis, techeles

If one is wearing techeiles strings on his tallis katan, and goes up to be shliach tzibbur (lead the prayer), may he put on a shul tallis (prayer shawl) that is non-techeiles, i.e., all white strings? The reverse works as well (someone wearing all white strings puts on a garment with techeiles strings).

The reason I think it may be not allowed is due to the issue of *tarti d'sasri*, meaning a mutual contradiction.

Comment: If someone doesn't have one of the colors, he wears just the other color (Menachot 4:1). Not sure what contradiction you're seeing here.

Comment: Rav Belsky only  wore techeiles on his talis katan and not his talis gadol. He isn't the only one .

Comment: @DoubleAA but if he has both colors and doesn't put them on, there is a possibility of bal tigra

Comment: @DoubleAA I second JoelK's comment. According to Rav Herschel Schachter, it could be a problem.

Comment: @JoelK is that the case here where you have two sets already tied and no extra strings lying around? Anyway...

Comment: ... bal tigra wasn't the question. @robev too

Comment: @DoubleAA the question was is there a problem? I agree they mentioned Tarti desasri, but I don't think they were being exclusive. `may he put on a shul tallis (prayer shawl) that is non-techeiles`

Comment: Just to clarify: I am asking if its allowed under any and all halachic considerations. I gave my thoughts on why I asked, but I am not limiting the question to only tarti d'sasri. Any proof why yes or why no is acceptable.

Comment: Would you have the same question if he wore techeiles on Sunday and white on Monday and then blue again on Tuesday etc?

Comment: There is no issue to daven in your shul as the baal kore with your techelet even if most of the others don’t. It is your tallis and that trumps anything else.

Comment: Even if one holds its a chov, wouldn't be doing something wrong if they use the shliach tzibbur talis since it is only done for kavod hatzibbur,for you the begged isn't even required in tzizts units the 30th day ...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the contradiction would be that your tzitis have tcheiles meaning your posek holds of that techeiles, whereas the tallis doesn't have tcheiles meaning whoever holds of it doesn't hold of tcheiles.
Putting aside the debate on whether we know what tcheiles is or not, wearing tzitzis with and without tzitzis isn't inherently contadictory - tcheiles is an additional assay, so wearing one pair of tzitzis with and one without isn't a problem.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem. How do you know? If the person who is wearing techeiles holds its true techeiles, then by wearing a Tallis without techeiles they're being mevatel the mitzvah of techeiles, no?

Comment: @robev that's true even if he isn't currently wearing one beged with blue

Comment: @DoubleAA but we're discussing when he is?

Comment: @robev we're discussing issues arising from his wearing both at the same time, which yours apparently isn't.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm saying maybe wearing a Tallis without techeiles is a bittul mitzvah even if they're wearing a Tallis with techeiles. Can they wear a Tallis without any tzitzis if they're wearing a Tallis with tzitzis? I don't think so...

Comment: @robev that's fine but doesn't answer the question of if there's something wrong with wearing with and without blue at the same time.

Comment: @robev Whether they hold its techeiles or not has no effect on anything. Why would it?

Comment: @KovyJacob I don't understand. If I have a legit reason to believe it's not techeiles so then it's no different than wearing black strings. I thought the question was assuming the wearer holds its real techeiles.

Comment: @robev If you hold it isn't its bal tosef, but why would that make waering one pair with and one pair without tarti disasri?

Comment: @KovyJacob wearing blue dye on tzitzis isn't Bal tosif. You can have your tzitzis any color. What's the tarti desasri. If I wear white tzitzis on one garment and one with red tzitzis...no problem. This discussion doesn't begin unless it's actually techeiles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

One example is Rav Belsky who only wore it on his tallit katan and never on his tallit gadol.

I guess it depends if you hold it is a chumrah/hiddur or a chiyuv.

If it is a chiyuv, then you can only wear techelet. See “[Tekhelet in Tzitzit: A choice Mitzvah or an Absolute Obligation](https://tekhelet.com/pdf/muvchar.pdf)” by R Samuel Ariel.

If it is a chumrah or hiddur , then you can wear only white if you don’t have techelet in that moment or not enough money etc. See “[The Definition of Nullifying a Mitzvah](https://tekhelet.com/pdf/bitulasei.pdf)” by R Yehuda Rock.

Most people who start wearing techelet hold is a chumrah  and do both at the same time for a while until they have enough money to fully switch to techelet.